# Python KeyError During Save/Load

Tags: python, python-3.x, save

So I was working on a program, and it used to SAVE/LOAD fine, and I have all the right imports and such, but recently, I've been getting this error message when I try to load (and a similar one during save):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shelve.py", line 111, in __getitem__
    value = self.cache[key]
KeyError: 'flipvariables'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\BascGames\ManorI\MANOR.py", line 241, in <module>
    flipvariables = sf['flipvariables']
  File "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\shelve.py", line 113, in __getitem__
    f = BytesIO(self.dict[key.encode(self.keyencoding)])
  File "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\dbm\dumb.py", line 147, in __getitem__
    pos, siz = self._index[key]     # may raise KeyError
KeyError: b'flipvariables'
```

The code that throws up the error (it is in two places, for two different times, but they have the exact same code -- this is the reload code, uses SHELVE):

```
flipvariables = {'papercomb': '', 'ropegiver': 'north', 'riddlenum': 1, 'theriddle': 'hi', 'riddleanswer': '?', 'passcode': '0', 'timesrealived': 0, 'rockkeydropped': 'no', 'maximumriddleguesses': 3, 'clutzmode': 'off', 'shortdesc': 'no', 'shortkeyss': {'qzz': 'die'}, 'shortkeys': ['qzz'], 'shortcommands': ['die'], 'saplasts': 5, 'riddlefailed': 'no', 'longdesc': 'no', 'waited': 0, 'intrivia': 'no', 'minimumtrivia': 2, 'goblinscore': 0, 'thicketscut': 'not', 'gascanfilled': 'no', 'lockout': 3, 'alarmactivated': 'on', 'holedug': 'no', 'wearinggloves': 'no', 'skeletonkicked': 'no', 'gettingtetanus': 'no', 'tetanusgotten': 'no', 'tetanusin': 3, 'turntoexplosion': 3, 'boatfixed': 'no', 'gargoylestatus': 'locked', 'safestatus': 'locked', 'disturbeddirtstatus': 'locked', 'scannerstatus': 'locked', 'toychestlookedat': 0, 'seedsplanted': 'no', 'flowersin': 4, 'flowersplanted': 'no'} 
#abridged version of the flipvariables mentioned in the code

first == input(">").lowercase()
if(first == 'reload'):
      slot = input("\nSavefile 1, 2 or 3? ").lower()
      if(slot == '1') or (slot == 'one'):
        cpon = os.path.isfile('C:\\BascGames\\ManorI\\SaveFiles\\1.dat')
      elif(slot == '2') or (slot == 'two'):
        cpon = os.path.isfile('C:\\BascGames\\ManorI\\SaveFiles\\2.dat')
      elif(slot == '3') or (slot == 'three'):
        cpon = os.path.isfile('C:\\BascGames\\ManorI\\SaveFiles\\3.dat')
      else:
        cpon = os.path.isfile('C:\\BascGames\\ManorI\\SaveFiles\\0.dat')
      if(cpon == False):
        print("\nThat savefile does not exist.")
      else:
        if(slot == '1') or (slot == 'one'):
          sf = shelve.open('C:\\BascGames\\ManorI\\SaveFiles\\1')
        elif(slot == '2') or (slot == 'two'):
          sf = shelve.open('C:\\BascGames\\ManorI\\SaveFiles\\2')
        elif(slot == '3') or (slot == 'three'):
          sf = shelve.open('C:\\BascGames\\ManorI\\SaveFiles\\3')
        else:
          sf = shelve.open('C:\\BascGames\\ManorI\\SaveFiles\\0')
          print("\nSavefile not avaliable. Opened savefile 0.\n")
        flipvariables = sf['flipvariables']
        inventory = sf['inventory']
        goblinstatuses = sf['goblinstatuses']
        roominventories = sf['roominventories']
        iteminventories = sf['iteminventories']
        health = sf['health']
        answersgot = sf['answersgot']
        avalweight = sf['avalweight']
        currentroom = sf['currentroom']
        yname = sf['yname']
        statuses = sf['statuses']
        gametoughness = sf['gametoughness']
        sf.close()
        print("\nReload sucessful!")
      flipvariables['roomchanged'] = 'yes'
```

Does anybody have any idea what this could be and how to fix it? Thanks in advance. I understand the basics, what it means about lines, but the base idea of the error doesn't make sense to me. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you want to post your code?

Comment: Would that be helpful? Just the save code or everything? The whole thing is very rather long. Do you just want the save code, or would the save code + parts mentioned be helpful? Open to it, just not sure how much would be required and it's a few thousand lines long

Comment: The code that throws the error.

Comment: No, we don't want to see thousands of lines. Please create a [mcve] that reproduces the error.

Comment: I've put up just the load code that is what produces this error when it is run. I type an input of RELOAD, and then type the SAVE FILE (1, 2 or 3) and it then prints out the error. I'll update it to have the inputs

Comment: It looks like `shelve` wants the keys to be `bytes`, like `b'flipvariables'`, but your code uses text string keys like `'flipvariables'`. They may _look_ almost the same, but `b'flipvariables' != 'flipvariables'`.

Comment: At the beginning, the big dictionary is called flipvariables, and it's **flipvariables = {}** (with stuff inside that). It has no ", ' or similar around it. In the load code, it is **flipvariables = sf['flipvariables']**. In the save code, it's **sf['flipvariables'] = flipvariables**

Comment: So would it be making the Save and Load codes just be flipvariables = sf[flipvariables] instead (and the equiv for Save?)

Comment: How would I convert the string to bytes?

Answer (score 0):

A key error is when the key for a dictionary doesn't exist. For example,

```
person = {name: 'joe', age: 41}
```

If I were to call for the key `last_name`using `person['last_name']`, Python would throw a `KeyError` because the key does not exist for the given dictionary.

In your error:
`KeyError: b'flipvariables'` means the key `flipvariables` does not exist for the given dictionary.

Based on the line `flipvariables = sf['flipvariables']` in your traceback, look at the `sf` dictionary in your code and see if the `flipvariables` key is there, and add it if necessary.

Comment: Note that `b'flipvariables' != 'flipvariables'`. The first one is a `bytes` string, the second one is a (Unicode) text string.

Comment: Thanks. flipvariables is already there, added (sf['flipvariables'] = flipvariables) to the SAVE file when it is saved, and the SAVE works fine. It is also the very first non-comment or inport piece of code, a massive dictionary containing about 100 dictionaries, arrays and strings. It is mentioned in the load file as seen above as well.

Comment: PM 2Ring: So what exactly does that mean with the b'flipvariables' != 'flipvariables. I get that they are not equal, but how would you fix that?